# Rendering with overlay of the previous frame?

Tags: rendering, animation

A million years ago (it is possible that this was in the 2000s...), Blender had a switch where you could optionally leave a previous frame visible when rendering the next output. In other words, when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, the first thing that I saw was the LAST image I rendered (perhaps the previous frame, when rendering an animation; or the same frame, but minus the edits I'd just made), and then Blender would gradually infill with the current render data. (This was almost certainly Blender Internal.)

Is that still a capability that exists? I've searched high and low in the docs, and "persisting" frame data isn't it. Am I searching for the wrong thing? Did this go away sometime in the past decade, sometime in the past 2 or 3 new rendering engines?